# Weird behaviour of Stream in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is regarding streams on a table that is getting emptied even though I am making sure of "on" condition is matching the 1:1 row in the source and target table.

Here is an example:

I have a stream on a table that has the following state.

```
backup, id, name, metadata$action
a, 1, Joe, DELETE
a, 2, Jane, DELETE
b, 1, Joe, INSERT
b, 2, Jane, INSERT
b, 3, Jake, INSERT
```

state before merge

```
backup, id, name
a,1,Joe
a,2,Jane
```

But when I insert it into the target table using merge statement using

MERGE INTO target USING  stream on (target.id = stream.id and  target.backup = stream.backup)
WHEN MATCHED  and  stream.metadata$action = 'DELETE'  THEN DELETE;

This deletes the target table as expected, but it empties the STREAM completely, even though the ON condition makes sure only 1:1 matching records are joined
and the condition states as DELETE. Because of this, I am losing all my INSERT rows in the stream.

Could you please let me know am I doing something wrong or this is the expected behavior of the stream?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using an explicit transaction statement?

From the Snowflake docs -

> To ensure multiple statements access the same change records in the stream, surround them with an explicit transaction statement (BEGIN .. COMMIT). An explicit transaction locks the stream, so that DML updates to the source table are not reported to the stream until the transaction is committed.

Source: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stream.html#usage-notes

Or you could just add another statement to handle the INSERT.

For example,

```
when matched
    and source_table.metadata$action = 'INSERT'
    and source_table.metadata$isupdate then
    update set target_table.text = source_table.text
when matched
    and source_table.metadata$action = 'DELETE' then 
    delete
when not matched
    and source_table.metadata$action = 'INSERT' then 
    insert 
    (whatever you want to insert)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because a DML statement which selects from a stream consumes all of the change data in the stream. Here the DML statement is DELETE. You may want to move the stream data to another table and then do the MERGE.

Comment: Hi Rajib, Thank you for your answer. I have updated the question, but it makes no sense for the stream to disappear completely without handling all the changes. I am making sure that there is only a 1:1 match with the source and target table. Even then the stream gets deleted completly.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Rajib's answer.

If you understand how a Snowflake stream physically works, it makes sense why it behaves this way (Personally, I don't like this behaviour, but I can see their logic).

The documentation explains that "a stream itself does not contain any table data. A stream only stores an offset for the source table and returns CDC records by leveraging the versioning history for the source table." (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams.html#offset-storage)

I.e. the stream just points to a specific change record in the source table. When you read from the stream (and the transaction is committed), it advances the pointer to the last change record in the source table at the point when you read data from the stream.

It can't take into account which change records were actually returned by the query, because they might not all have been in sequence. There might be change records a, b and c in the source table, if your query only selects change records a and c, the stream still has to advance the pointer to change c (essentially dropping change b from the stream).

I've had to change my approach to working with streams as a result of this behaviour, and we now move all the data from the stream into a "holding" table before working with it.